# Pagination: Is this how it works?

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to setup pagination at the bottom of my article template.

What I want to achieve is the following:

To link to the first group of 5 pages, to show links for the next 5 pages and to link to the next group of 5 pages.

The pagination links appear but the numbered links link to pages P14, P28, & P42.

Here is my code:

```
{paginate}
{if {total_pages} > 1}
<nav class="centered" role="toolbar">
<ul class="pagination">
{pagination_links page_padding="5"}
{previous_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>{/previous_page}

{page}<li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>{/page}

{next_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>{/next_page}
{/pagination_links}
</ul>
</nav>
{/if}
{/paginate}
```

[image: pagination links]

Why is it linking to every 14th page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it linking to every 14th page?

It's not. I'm willing to bet that your `channel:entries` tag has a `limit` of `14`. The links/url segments indicate *entry* offset, not *page* offset - but they achieve the same end result.

Comment: Yes the channel entries tag has a limit of 14.

Comment: So does that mean that domain.com/P14 is essentially page 2?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that.